# Как отменить последний push?

Tags: git

Допустим сделал push, но теперь нужно отменить этот последний пуш из-за ошибки.
Как это правильно сделать?  Ветка master

**P.S.**
по просьбе выложил ответ от команды `git reflog`, названия коммитов вымышленные, т.к. на задачу большого значения не влияют

```
$ git reflog
4e212ca (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{0}: commit: мой последний коммит
e12ea6d HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD^
132ae6f HEAD@{2}: commit: ещё один коммит
e43ea6d HEAD@{3}: commit: ещё один коммит
2234538 HEAD@{4}: pull: Fast-forward
89543c9 HEAD@{5}: commit: fix search
```

Comment: какая ошибка была?

Comment: просто чуть не то сделал и запушил

Comment: сделайте коммит-откат (git revert) и запуште. push c force - это очень плохо (особенно, если работаете в команде)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Откатывать запушенные на сервер файлы во многих командах не
>   рекомендуется, так как их могли уже забрать с сервера.
>
> Также настоятельно рекомендуется сделать резервную копию, скачав всё
>   содержимое папки в какое-либо другое место.

В принципе, если вы работали из командной строки и ещё не успели её закрыть – то можете просто посмотреть, какой коммит был последним:

```
git commit -m "asdf"
[master 6703d65] asdf
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)

git push
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 407 bytes | 407.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git.mydomain.tld:folder/repo.git
   743acea..6703d65  master -> master
```

Последняя строчка говорит, что ДО push'а последний коммит был 743acea, а стал 6703d65 - вот и вернитесь к 743acea:

```
git reset --hard 743acea
git push --force
```

Также если вы закрыли консоль (либо у вас UI в котором не видны действия), но вы уверены, что ничего после push не делали - вам помогут команды:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push --force
```

Вообще же лучше всего прочитать рефлог (`git reflog`) и откатиться к нужному коммиту через HEAD@{1} (уточните цифру сколько действий нужно отменить именно в вашем случае):

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
git push --force
```

Открываем reflog:

```
$ git reflog

6703d65 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{0}: commit: asdf
743acea HEAD@{1}: commit: asdf
1a4e976 HEAD@{2}: commit: something

...
```

Ваша задача — найти в этом логе тот пункт, к которому вы хотите вернуться:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

Comment: @A K, подскажите, в одних случаях пишется `git reset --hard HEAD~1` , в других случаях пишется `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`. т.е. номер коммита. Чем этот синтаксис отличается?

Comment: @word Тем, что в случае `~` вы отсчитываете относительно коммитов, а `@` вы отсчитываете относительно действий. Например, git rebase при просмотре reflog'а может вылиться в длинный список `@` и откатываться в середину действий вообще не рекомендуется. Надёжнее в вашем случае будет прочитать рефлог (приведите его вывод в вопросе), хотя и HEAD~1 в большинстве случаев сработает так как надо. Просто, чтобы вам не попасть в те крайне малые доли случаев, когда вы поручились, что больше ничего не делали, а на самом деле да и вы начали откатываться между коммитами... а ещё не дай бог без бекапа...

Comment: @A K, подскажите ещё плз, что именно делает команда `git push --force`

Comment: форс делает следующее - она говорит серверу, то что у тебя есть - неправильно, не пытайся мерждить, просто возьми мои коммиты и сделай как у меня.

Answer (score -1):

Если мне не изменяет память, то сносим текущий коммит `git reset --hard HEAD~1` и затем пушим заново `git push origin HEAD --force`
Или как вариант зайти туда, где запушили, и там снести последний коммит. Я вторым способом пользовался лично

Comment: не нужно так делать. Если запушены пароли/явки, то уже поздно. Нужно их менять.

Comment: @KoVadim а что именно в этом ответе неправильно? первая или вторая команда?
Ведь первая команда совпадает с ответом выше. Что делает вторая команда?

Comment: не нужно форсированно пушить. В моей практике было всего два случая, когда форсированный пуш был нужен - в одном случае человек удалил все файлы (десятки тысяч) и заммитил. Во втором человек закомитил просто какой то мусор в репозиторий.

Comment: @KoVadim, а в моей практике было полно таких случаев. Более того, они встречаются довольно часто. Быть может не стоит экстраполировать _свою_ практику на других людей, пытаясь давать _общие советы_.

Comment: скорее всего в Ваших случаях не нужно было делать форсированный пуш.

Answer (score -1):

Сперва отправьте изменения в правильную ветку (в удалённом репозитории проверьте, что в mytask все изменения были приняты, т.е. что последний коммит прошёл, иначе есть шанс потерять всю работу)

```
git push origin mytask
```

Потом, на мастере получите все изменения из удалённой репы:

```
git checkout master
git fetch --all
git rebase origin/master
```

Сбросить изменения и вернуть их на мастер с форсом:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push origin master -f
```

Ну и как выше написали, откатывать запушенные на сервер файлы во многих командах не рекомендуется, так как их могли уже забрать с сервера.